# Avoid repeating same coder over and over

Tags: php

well I have written myself PHP to ping an end point and return if its up or down, simple ! done that..... Well what if I want to do the same but to half a dozen or more end points ? Will repeating the same over make it slow and inefficient ? Is there a simpler way to use the same part of code over without the cut and paste ?

Section of code I am using:-

```
      $str1=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.4",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str1)>1){
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
```

Is repeating the same code OK or is there a better way to achieve this :-

```
  $str1=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.4",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str1)>1){
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
  $str2=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.5",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str2)>1){
$output2 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output2 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
  $str3=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.6",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str3)>1){
$output3 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output3 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
  $str4=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.7",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str4)>1){
$output4 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output4 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
```

IE could I have a list of IP as variable and call each one in turn ?

```
$ip1 = 1.2.3.4
$ip2 = 1.2.3.5
$ip3 = 1.2.3.6
$ip4 = 1.2.3.7
```

Thanks all.

Comment: why don't you use an array of ip addresses and than do a loop over them?

Comment: Yes, you could. It's called a function. Even the most basic PHP tutorial should teach you how to make one.

Comment: There is an amazing programming concept called “functions”, which can be called with “parameters” ... suggest you go read up on that.

Comment: FUNCTIONS ! Brill.... I will go and read.

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, you should mark it. If not then you might want to edit the question with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

As the overly sarky comments suggested functions are what you're after. You've correctly identified which piece of your code you're repeating:

```
$str1=exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.4",$a,$a1);
  if(strlen($str1)>1){
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
} else{
$output1 = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";
}
```

Therefore you could easily make a `ping()` function to handle the code.

```
function ping($ip) {
    $output = [];
    $status = '';

    $cmd = 'ping -c 1 -w 1 ' . $ip;
    $result = exec($cmd, $output, $status);

    return $result;
}
```

Usage would be something like the following:

```
$ips = [
    '255.255.255.0',
    '255.255.255.1',
    '255.255.255.2',
];

$successImage = "<img src=\"images/green.png\">";
$failureImage = "<img src=\"images/red.png\">";

foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    $result = ping($ip);
    echo (strlen($result) > 1) ? $successImage : $failureImage;
}
```

Edit: It's probably worth noting that within `ping()` `$output` and `$status` aren't used, so you could remove them, along with the optional arguments in `exec()`. [Documentation for exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Bonus bit of functionality you may want to look into is making your ping arguments `-c 1 -w 1` a parameter which can be passed to the function. That way you can re-use the function for any other ping use cases you may come across in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try something close to this:

```
<?php
$ips = array('name1' => '1.2.3.4', 'name2' => '1.2.3.5');

function ping( $ips, $a = 'default', $a1 = 'default' ) {
  foreach( $ips as $key => $value ) {
     $str1 = exec( 'ping -c 1 -w 1 '.$value, $a, $a1 );

     if( strlen( $str1 ) > 1 ) {
        echo $key.' <img src="images/green.png">';
     } else {
       echo $key.' <img src="images/red.png">';
     }
  }
}
```

In `$ips` all ip addresses are stored along with a name. The name isn't required but it can be usefull for identifying The function takes 3 params `$ips` = array, `$a` and `$a1` both of which can have a default setting in the paramaters itself. You can add more params as needed.

You call the function simply by using:

```
echo ping($ips);
```

If you do need to change `$a` and `$a1` for a specific case use:

```
echo ping($ips, 'a setting', 'a1 setting');
```